# How to deploy docker image on container through kubernetes YAML file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am new to `Kubernetes` and trying my first deployment. Main Content of `Docker` file:

```
..........
..........
COPY . $PROJECT_HOME
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["sbt"]
```

I can successfully build the container `image` using the following command `docker build -t fitmeold:0.3 .`

To deploy the `image` on a `container` using docker I used the following command:

```
docker run  -it -p 80:9000 fitmeold:0.3 --name fitmeold sbt run
```

were as

1. `-p` for port forwarding because `sbt` will run the project default on `9000` port.
2. `fitmeold:0.3` is my image name
3. `sbt run` to pass `Command argument`

Instead of the building through `docker build`, I want to use the `Kubernetes` to deploy the 
 `fitmeold:0.3` `container` with the `replication` factor. My  `YAML` file looks like this:

```
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "fitmeold"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "fitmeold"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "fitmeold"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "fitmeold"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: "fitmeold"
          image: "fitmeold:0.3"
          command:
            - "-p 80:8000 -it sbt run"
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "fitmeold-hpa"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "fitmeold"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "fitmeold"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
    - type: "Resource"
      resource:
        name: "cpu"
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

Is this the right way to pass the `command arguments` through `YAML` file or is it equivalent to `docker build` command?

If that's correct why I am getting `ImagePullBackOff` as in status for each `pods`. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong and how to pass the equivalent docker build command argument in `YAML` file.

Comment: If you're getting `ImagePullBackOff` errors that means the Kubernetes system can't find your image on Docker Hub; the `command:` will try to run a command `-p` which probably doesn't exist either.  [Run a Stateless Application Using a Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/) in the Kubernetes documentation might be a good starting point, along with [Use a Service to Access an Application in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/).

Comment: `ImagePullBackOff` doesn't mean it can't find the image.

Answer (score 1):

use the below yamls

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: fitmeold
  name: fitmeold
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: fitmeold
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: fitmeold
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: fitmeold:0.3
        command: ["sbt run"]
        name: fitmeold
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: fitmeold
  name: fitmeold
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    run: fitmeold
```

Comment: Thanks for putting your answer but how can I pass the other command such as `-it` and how this forwarding port working here?

Comment: option -it is for interactive terminal. you dont need to use that option if you want to deploy the app

Answer (score 0):

The "ImagePullBackOff" status indicate that the image used by a container cannot be loaded from the [image registry](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting#ImagePullBackOff). Basically it means you didn't pull your image to Docker hub.

To troubleshoot this, please run on your computer:

```
$ kubectl describe pod <NAME_OF_YOUR_POD>
```

From the events list you get, it should appear at least one with "Failed" reason. Please check out the explanation for the event.

In case you see a message like "Error response from daemon: repository  not found: does not exist or no pull access" please pull your image by:

```
$ docker login (provide user and password)
$ docker pull [IMAGE_NAME]
```